# Ideal Voltages connected in Parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, voltage

[image]

I tried to solve the above circuit. Using superposition, I got $I = 2$, but using loop law I got $I =1$. Also I got that the current through the batteries can be any real value from 0 to infinity.

How do I calculate the current through the branches of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

> Using superposition, I got I=2,

This is your mistake. You used superposition incorrectly. Using superposition you should have gotten undefined.

When solving a circuit using superposition you take one source at a time and remove all of the other sources. Current sources are removed by turning them into open paths, but voltage sources are removed by turning them into shorts.

In the above circuit, when you replace one voltage source with a short circuit you get an unsolvable circuit. You get a voltage which at the same time must be 2 V (because of the remaining voltage source) and 0 V (because of the short circuit). This is impossible, so the single-source current is undefined. This repeats when you remove the first voltage source. Two undefined currents give an undefined total current, not 2 A.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to also be able to look at the situation and just think about it. That will give you a better intuitive sense of both superposition and loop law as you practice them on simple circuits and get better. Then you’ll be much more likely to use them correctly on more complex circuitry.

Let’s just think about this problem. The batteries are pointed the same way, and the battery ends are connected directly without resistance inductance etc between them. Any points directly connected without resistance etc will be at the same voltage. So we know crossing one battery the voltage changes by two. And that is the voltage for that entire half of this circuit. That means the two halves of this circuit are 2 volts apart.

The current is the amount of current driven by two volts. (It’s good to think of current as a flow being driven by a voltage difference): $V=IR$

So the answer is 1. Now you can see what may have gone wrong with superposition.

Comment: Moved this to comment because confuses it: In this sense voltage is like height; if something is two feet above this and two feet above that and they are next to each other, it is not four feet right? But they add in series. / Current is like a flow. Currents in parallel add, like two hoses next to each other makes more total flow. Currents in series is like two hoses in series, they don’t add and in fact they better be equal.

Answer (score 0):

> Using superposition, i got I = 2, but using loop law i got I =1.

In ideal circuit theory connecting two ideal constant voltage sources (batteries having zero internal resistance) in parallel results in a contradiction.

Looking at each side of the circuit separately (what you call superposition) each battery would be delivering 1 ampere to the 2 Ohm resistor for a total current in the 2 Ohm resistor of 2 A. Then, from Ohms law $V=IR$, the voltage across the 2 Ohm resistor would be 2x2=4 volts. You can't have both 2 volts and 4 volts across the same two points in a circuit. Thus a contradiction.

The situation can be resolved by including a resistor is series with each battery to represent the internal resistance that exists in all real batteries. Let's assume the two batteries are identical and each has an internal resistance of $r_b$. See the circuit diagram below.

Kirchhoff's voltage law is applied to each loop, as shown in the diagram. Subtracting the second loop equation from the first gives you

$$I_{2}r_{b}-I_{1}r_{b}=0$$

$$I_{1}=I_{2}$$

Then substituting $I_{1}$ for $I_{2}$ in either equation gives you

$$2=I_{1}(4+r_{B})$$

Note that as the internal resistance of each battery approaches zero, $I_{1}$, and thus $I_2$, approaches 1/2 A for a total current through the resistor approaching 1 A. But $r_b$ can not actually equal zero because the presence of the resistance was needed to prevent the contradiction and establish the relationship between $I_1$ and $I_2$, in this case, $I_{1}=I_{2}$ for identical real batteries.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Did that help or..?  Oversimplified it?